# mysql lock tables from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, locking

I have a bash script that is trying to lock specific tables in my database as READ Only. This is the command I'm trying to execute:

```
 mysql -u root -p -e "LOCK TABLES db_name.table1 READ, db_name.table2 READ;"
```

This isn't actually locking the tables though, as I am able to update the tables that I'm attempting to lock above. When I run the following commands right from the shell it works:

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

(This takes me into mysql where I enter the following)

```
 LOCK TABLES db_name.table1 READ, db_name.table2 READ;
```

And this actually locks the tables in the database as I am unable to write anything or update anything in those tables.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: mysql cleans up when a connection is closed. your cli would lock the tables, then exit, causing mysql to clean up and release the locks. you'd have to maintain the connection the whole time you want the locks to be active.

Comment: @MarcB do you want to just paste that into an answer so we can wrap this one up? Or Samantha you do it. It *is* the answer.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you!! Keeping the connection active the whole time works perfectly.

Comment: How did you do the task? Can you please post the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cleans up when a connection is closed. That means your `mysql ....` command-line will connect, lock the tables, then exit - closing the connection, causing the locks to be released.

You need to maintain that "lock" connection the whole time you want/need the locks to stay set.

Comment: How to maintain the `lock` connection from cli (shell script)?

Answer (score -1):

Per Marc B's comment above :

mysql cleans up when a connection is closed. your cli would lock the tables, then exit, causing mysql to clean up and release the locks. you'd have to maintain the connection the whole time you want the locks to be active

Comment: Duplicate of @Marc's Answer and Comment.